# Modifying vector image in Android

Tags: android, vector

I am looking for number 1 to be like this. Dont mind the color.

[image]

What I have managed to acheive is

[image]

with the following code.

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M12, 2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12, 2zM13,17h-1L12, 9h-2L10, 7h4v10z"/>
```

Not so expert with vector points in Android. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Transform the [image into svg](https://www.pngtosvg.com/), then use the vector asset in android studio to get the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a vector, I used `Image asset`. Here we could change the font and choose according to our needs. Hope this helps for someone in future.

[image]